# Inferring distribution from summary statistics

Tags: distributions

A study reports that a sample of $276$ independent integer measurements from the closed range $[0, 65]$ has a sample mean of $21.39$ and a sample standard deviation of $65$.

*Is it possible to infer anything about the shape of the sample distribution from this information only?*

(Asking out of curiosity while reading some study reports)

Comment: It sounds like an error. The maximum possible standard deviation on values in [0,65] with a mean of 21.39 seems to be about 30.56. I'd expect it's probably no more than 10-12 and possibly a good deal less. 6.5 *might* be a reasonable standard deviation but a missing decimal point is merely a guess.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can estimate a SD from any distribution or any vector of numbers, and it does not help you to identify a distribution. Also, how can the SD be equal to 65, given that the range is in [0,65]?

Comment: "Also, how can the SD be equal to 65, given that the range is in [0,65]?"
A typo perhaps? Or fabricated numbers?